# iPhone loses SMSs after software update

Tags: iphone, restore, sms, software-update

I recently updated my iPhone 4 to iOS 4.3.1. Everything seemed to go fine. However, after I sent my next text message the phone quickly showed the restart screen and then all my old messages were deleted. Thinking it was a fluke I restored to before the update. Everything (except the messages I had sent between the update and restore) showed up again. However, again, as soon as I sent another text, my phone restarted and all the old messages were removed. I'd like to keep my old SMSs on my phone and still be able to send/receive new ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: Next time before you do a software update, back up all your data that you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Open up "Settings" then tap on "General" and scroll down to the last option "Reset". Tap the third option "Reset Network Settings". This will take a few seconds and then your phone will restart.

**BE ADVISED** Doing this will deleted your saved wireless network passwords and wireless network history so you will have to reenter these passwords to reconnect to wireless networks. This option does *not* delete any of your personal data off your phone.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can give you is to go the Apple Store Genius Bar or your local Apple Authorized reseller. That certainly seems like a particularly bad bug.

I can only hope that it has been fixed in the year since you posted this question.